# Code Contracts -- Requires/Ensures unproven when I use IComparable or IComparable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, require, code-contracts, icomparable

I have the following method:

```
public static bool IsBetween<T>(this IComparable<T> value, T lowerBound, T upperBound)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    Contract.Requires<>(value != null);
    Contract.Requires<>(lowerBound != null);
    Contract.Requires<>(upperBound != null);
    Contract.Requires<>(upperBound.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0);

    return IsBetween(value, lowerBound, upperBound, InclusionOptions.None);
}

public static bool IsBetween<T>(this IComparable<T> value, T lowerBound, T upperBound,
     InclusionOptions options) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    Contract.Requires<>(value != null);
    Contract.Requires<>(lowerBound != null);
    Contract.Requires<>(upperBound != null);
    Contract.Requires<>(upperBound.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0); //Code Contracts Issue

    ...
}
```

The problem here is that it does not like my last requirement. It states `CodeContracts: requires unproven: upperBound.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0`. I'm not really sure the proper way to fix this here. I need to make sure that when I do my comparison values that I actually have a real lowerBound and upperBound value and that the lowerBound value is not above the upperBound value.

Oh, and I can't use the actual < or > operators because you can't apply them to the type 'T'.

---

Lastly, I know this *can* be a separate question, but it's highly related... if someone knows why I still get CA1062 Code Analysis errors when I'm using Code Contracts v1.4.50126.1 please tell me what to do to fix it: `CA1062: Microsoft.Design : In externally visible method 'MyClass.IsBetween<T>(this IComparable<T>, T, T), validate parameter 'upperBound' before using it.`

Comment: I haven’t used `Contract`, but wouldn’t the warning be relevant to the code which is _calling_ your method, rather than the method definition itself? Do you have any calls in your application where you’re violating the condition?

Comment: Nope. This in my utility class. No code in that class calls this member. It is 100% isolated.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the CA1062 analysis. It is currently incompatible with Code Contracts, and Code Contracts will warn you anyway if you have potential issues.

Comment: @m-y: *something* has to be calling that code, or Code Contracts wouldn't generate the warning. The warning means that the calling code does not prove that the requirements are correct.

Comment: @Porges: You're right, I didn't realize that I had a method named `IsBetween` that had an additional parameter calling into this method. But, it still doesn't explain why I can't use `Requires` and/or `Result` with `IComparable`/`IComparable<T>`. They're simply method calls which return true/false.

Comment: @m-y: can you post the calling code as well?

Comment: @Porges: Done... I think I might know of a solution to this, which is to not use `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>` in my requirements and allow the lowerBound/upperBound values to be passed in either order, then calculate which should be the upperBound/lowerBound from within because one has to be an upperBound in comparison to the other (even if they are equal).

Comment: @m-y: this looks like a bug in CC. The Requires on the calling method should be proving this, but it isn't. As an aside, I'd change the first parameter from `IComparable<T>` to `T`. At the moment, the parameter will have to be boxed, which will impact performance, especially since this method will be used with primitive values 99% of the time. I've reported this as a bug on the CC forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/codecontracts/thread/7ed5f4af-df26-4326-ab7d-7f2512e7fbf6

Comment: @Porges: I left it as `IComparable<T>` because LINQ's extension methods use `IEnumerable<T>` as the parameter, so I figured that's the pattern to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your method is that, when you call `upperBound.CompareTo`, you are assuming that the compiler knows that type `T` (which is the declared type of the `upperBound` parameter) implements the `IComparable<T>` interface (which declares the `CompareTo` method).

It is typically always the case (by convention) that an `IComparable<T>` interface would be implemented by the type `T` (if at all); however, the compiler does not know it unless you explicitly specify it through a type constraint.

```
public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T value, T lowerBound, T upperBound)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    Contract.Requires(value != null);
    Contract.Requires(lowerBound != null);
    Contract.Requires(upperBound != null);
    Contract.Requires(upperBound.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry... in my haste I forgot to put down that I do have a type constraint... but I don't see that having anything to do with the line that has an issue.

Comment: The line would fail to compile if you don’t add the type constraint.

Comment: Douglas: I do have that line (hence it compiles). In my haste to copy my code over and format it to look well in Stackoverflow deleted the constraint line. I do have a generic constraint. I have updated my question to reflect my method accurately.

Comment: @m-y: Added comment beneath your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use `int` as an example.

The contract for `int.CompareTo(int)` does not ensure any particular return value. *You* know that if `a >= b`, then `a.CompareTo(b) >= 0`, but since this has not been expressed as a contract, the only thing the static checker sees is "a.CompareTo(b) returns an int". "An int" cannot be proven to be nonnegative.

You should be able to add something like

```
Contract.Assert(a >= b);
Contract.Assume(a.CompareTo(b) >= 0);
```

in the places you call your function. This lets the static checker first attempt to prove that `a >= b` and notify you if it cannot prove that, and then trust you that the function requirement is met.

If you often call this function for an `int`, it may be worthwhile to create a wrapper function with this modified `int`-specific contract:

```
public static bool IsBetween(this int value, int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    Contract.Requires<>(value != null);
    Contract.Requires<>(lowerBound != null);
    Contract.Requires<>(upperBound != null);
    Contract.Requires<>(upperBound >= lowerBound);
    Contract.Assume(upperBound.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0);
    return IsBetween<int>(value, lowerBound, upperBound);
}
```

and similarly for other types.